# If $a\frac {dy}{dx} + by = c$ has constant coeffcients, does that means that $a=b=c$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definition

I am trying to identify if a differential equation has constant coefficients.

Let $A = a\dfrac {dy}{dx} + by = c$

The $A$ has constant coefficients only if $a=b=c$ correct?

Comment: **I** call $3y'+5y=2$ an ODE with constant coefficients. Truth be told, I even call $3y'+5y=e^{-x}$ an ODE with constant coefficients.

Comment: It has constant coefficients if $a,b$ are numbers, rather than functions of $x$ or $y$.

Comment: Thanks. Why is that???

Comment: If a or be are functions of y then it is not linear.

Comment: No, it means that the coefficients $a$ and $b$ are constants (that is to say, they are not functions of $x$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general form of an ODE is
$$F(x,y,y',y'',...,y^{[n]})=g(x)$$
We call it **homogeneous** if $g(x)=0$. (Well, this isn't technically precise, but I hope you get the idea.) We call it **linear** if it is of the form
$$p_0(x)y+p_1(x)y'+...+p_n(x)y^{[n]}=g(x)$$
We call it **constant coefficient** if it is of the form
$$c_0q_0(y)+c_1q_1(y')+...+c_nq_n(y^{[n]})=g(x)$$
Where $c_0,...,c_n$ are constants but are *not necessarily equal*.

Comment: In general, homogeneous means that with $y(x)$ also $\alpha y(x)$ for any factor $\alpha\in \Bbb R$, or more generally $\alpha y(\alpha^qx)$, for some fixed $q$, is also a solution. So your first sentence is very far from the truth, in the "$y$ is a vector" case, the implicit equation may not even be an ODE, it could also be a DAE or worse.

Answer (score 3):

Let us look to some examples:

Homogeneous equations with constant coefficients:

- $y'+y=0$
- $2y'+y=0$
- $y'+3y=0$
- $2y'+3y=0$

Nonhomogeneous equations with constant coefficients:

- $y'+y=1$
- $2y'+y=1+x$
- $y'+3y=x^2$
- $2y'+3y=e^x$

Homogeneous equations with variable coefficients:

- $xy'+y=0$
- $y'+x^2y=0$
- $e^xy'+y=0$
- $xy'+e^xy=0$

Nonhomogeneous equations with variable coefficients:

- $xy'+y=1$
- $y'+x^2y=1+x$
- $e^xy'+y=x^2$
- $xy'+e^xy=e^x$

In general, a first-order linear differential equation has constant coefficients if it has the form
$$a\frac{dy}{dx}+by=c$$
with $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$ and $a\neq 0$.